# Embadding video is not displaying after retrieving it from dataabse

Tags: java, mysql, video, jstl, embedding

i am saving embedding video code in database and retrieving it from database but it is not displaying video it is displaying just code in place of video.

**Video Link:**

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=1418261161721629" width="1024" height="576" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

**Code to display embedding Video:**

```
<div class="products">
<ul>  
    <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">                 
<li class="first">
          <c:out value="${row.video_link}"/>
     </li>
    </c:forEach>
   </ul>            
 </div>
```

Comment: what error/s are you receiving? also this post is vague. please provide a code sample

Comment: I am not receiving any error but i am receiving the <iframe> code that i have saved in database. in place of video